# pipenv reference another python version

Tags: python, pipenv

My python version is 3.6.5.

But if I entered pipenv, it throws error.

```
➜  akak pipenv
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26_1/libexec/bin/python3.7
  Reason: image not found
[1]    1407 abort      pipenv
```

Maybe `Referenced from` is keypoint of error.

It refered python3.7, But my python version is 3.6.5.

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

(I installed pipenv through `pip install pipenv --user`)

Comment: What happens when you run `python -V`?

Comment: @Shayn python -V -> `Python 3.6.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Python binary when you create a new pipenv project like this:

```
pipenv --python 3.6.5
```

This will force your version to be used.

Answer (score 2):

To create an environment, do:

```
pipenv --python=python3.6
```

If you already have *Pipfile*, to create an environment and install dependencies, do:

```
pipenv install
```

In some situations, the above command has failed throwing the

> TypeError exception: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

I have solved this by setting the version of python in the install command:

```
pipenv install --python=python3.6
```